# Theme.of(context) as const

Tags: flutter, dart

I have several places with repetitive codes, for `BoxDecoration`

```dart
decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Theme.of(context).hintColor.withOpacity(0.15),
                          offset: Offset(0, 3),
                          blurRadius: 10)
                    ],
                  ),
```

So I'd like to extract the `BoxDecoration` into separated dart file and reuse it.
Something like

```dart
static const boxDecoration = BoxDecoration(...);
```

then use it

```dart
final container = Container(
decoration: boxDecoration
)
```

But I get stuck on few things:
1. If I put it on file that only contains constants, I still need to access `context`, e.g. in `Theme.of(context).primaryColor`, which can only retrieved from `build(Context)` method
2. Then, I create a new stateless widget

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FlutterTemplateStyle extends StatelessWidget {
  static var boxDecoration;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    boxDecoration = BoxDecoration(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: Theme.of(context).hintColor.withOpacity(0.15),
            offset: Offset(0, 3),
            blurRadius: 10)
      ],
    );

    return Container();
  }
}
```

And try to access `decoration: FlutterTemplateStyle.boxDecoration`, which doesn't work. I suppose this is because `build` is never called.

How can I achieve this constant styling?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use `const` with **any** method call because methods cannot be evaluated at compile time - which is the requirement for a `const` value.

If you know that your `primaryColor` is constant, will never change, and that you will never want to dynamically change the color of your decoration, you can specify the color without the theme: `color: const Color(0xfef1d2e1)`.
Otherwise, *you do not want to use `const`*. You might want to use `final` if you never reassign your variable, however, that will not work if you need to access your `context`.

Having said that, you will probably just want to create a function that returns your decoration, so you can use it in multiple places:

```dart
BoxDecoration myAwesomeBoxDecoration(BuildContext context) => BoxDecoration(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Theme.of(context).hintColor.withOpacity(0.15),
          offset: const Offset(0, 3),
          blurRadius: 10,
        ),
      ],
    );
```

---

Let me explain why I believe that the thought of making your `BoxDecoration` a **constant** is counterintuitive:

The color of your decoration *depends on the theme of your app*, which is something that is created entirely at runtime. This means that in order for your `BoxDecoration` to adapt to the `Theme`, it cannot be *constant* because it is *adaptive*.